# Drupal defining node grid data

Tags: drupal, grid, drupal-nodes

I need to define a 10*10 grid of nodes. Each cell in the grid has to contain exactly one node.

A newly created node gets inserted into the next available cell and a new node can not be step to occupy an occupied cell.

That's the scenario I am trying to accomplish but I need suggestions how I do it.

Answer (score -1):

How are your nodes currently being displayed?  What version of Drupal are you using?

If you are using Views 7.x-3.x, there's a style plugin called "Grid" bundled with the module.  When editing your view, click on Format and select Grid.  Click "Apply", and on the following page set the number of columns to 10.

Finally, you probably want to disable the Views pager, but limit the results to 100.

Comment: Thanks for your great suggestion. The site is built in D6 and I am not doing anything extra ordinary to display my nodes at the moment. The displaying is not the problem. The problem is the actual mechanism for setting the nodes into unique cells in my grid. I am looking for an smart solution to place my nodes into the next available cell and prevent more than one node begin assigned to a single cell.

Comment: The Views 6.x module and the Grid style plugin can do what you're looking for, although note it uses tables to handle the formatting.

Comment: thank you. Views and the grid style will be useful later but right now, I am looking for ideas on how best to logically organize my nodes into grids rather than the physical layout views will help me with ???